# rapidjson error: expected unqualified-id before 'bool' when building for Linux using Bazel

Tags: c++, rapidjson

I'm compiling some C++ code that compiles fine for Android and iOS but fails under Linux. I've searched around and it looks like this kind of crash shows up when the implementer does something wrong; such as, using a reserved word. However I fail to see what I am doing wrong based on the error I'm getting.

```
In file included from external/rapidjson_artifact/include/rapidjson/document.h:20:0,
             from src/main/cc/com/mycompany/serialization/JsonSerializer.h:4,
             from bazel-out/k8-dbg/genfiles/src/main/java/com/mycompany/model/common/cc/com

/mycompany/model/common/Vector2d.h:13,
                 from bazel-out/k8-dbg/genfiles/src/main/java/com/mycompany/model/common/cc/com/mycompany/model/common/FastVector2d.h:10,
                 from src/main/cc/com/mycompany/api/gestures/primitives/CalculatedElementPosition.h:7,
                 from src/main/cc/com/mycompany/api/gestures/primitives/PointerInteraction.h:7,
                 from src/main/cc/com/mycompany/api/gestures/native/NativeUserInteractionHandler.h:10,
                 from src/main/cc/com/mycompany/linux/api/gestures/UserInteractionHandler.h:4,
                 from src/main/cc/com/mycompany/linux/api/opengl/OpenGlHandler.h:13,
                 from src/main/cc/com/mycompany/linux/api/opengl/OpenGlHandler.cc:1:
external/rapidjson_artifact/include/rapidjson/reader.h:189:15: error: expected unqualified-id before 'bool'
     bool Bool(bool) { return static_cast<Override&>(*this).Default(); }
               ^~~~
external/rapidjson_artifact/include/rapidjson/reader.h:189:15: error: expected ')' before 'bool'
In file included from /usr/include/GL/glx.h:30:0,
                 from src/main/cc/com/mycompany/linux/api/opengl/OpenGlHandler.h:7,
                 from src/main/cc/com/mycompany/linux/api/opengl/OpenGlHandler.cc:1:
external/rapidjson_artifact/include/rapidjson/reader.h: In member function 'void rapidjson::GenericReader<SourceEncoding, TargetEncoding, StackAllocator>::ParseTrue(InputStream&, Handler&)':
external/rapidjson_artifact/include/rapidjson/reader.h:623:26: error: expected unqualified-id before 'int'
             if (!handler.Bool(true))
                          ^
external/rapidjson_artifact/include/rapidjson/reader.h:623:26: error: expected ')' before 'int'
external/rapidjson_artifact/include/rapidjson/reader.h: In member function 'void rapidjson::GenericReader<SourceEncoding, TargetEncoding, StackAllocator>::ParseFalse(InputStream&, Handler&)':
external/rapidjson_artifact/include/rapidjson/reader.h:636:26: error: expected unqualified-id before 'int'
             if (!handler.Bool(false))
                          ^
external/rapidjson_artifact/include/rapidjson/reader.h:636:26: error: expected ')' before 'int'
external/rapidjson_artifact/include/rapidjson/document.h: In member function 'bool rapidjson::GenericValue<Encoding, Allocator>::Accept(Handler&) const':
external/rapidjson_artifact/include/rapidjson/document.h:1539:44: error: expected unqualified-id before 'int'
         case kFalseType:    return handler.Bool(false);
                                            ^
external/rapidjson_artifact/include/rapidjson/document.h:1539:44: error: expected ';' before 'int'
external/rapidjson_artifact/include/rapidjson/document.h:1540:44: error: expected unqualified-id before 'int'
         case kTrueType:     return handler.Bool(true);
                                            ^
external/rapidjson_artifact/include/rapidjson/document.h:1540:44: error: expected ';' before 'int'
In file included from src/main/cc/com/mycompany/serialization/JsonSerializer.h:4:0,
                 from bazel-out/k8-dbg/genfiles/src/main/java/com/mycompany/model/common/cc/com/mycompany/model/common/Vector2d.h:13,
                 from bazel-out/k8-dbg/genfiles/src/main/java/com/mycompany/model/common/cc/com/mycompany/model/common/FastVector2d.h:10,
                 from src/main/cc/com/mycompany/api/gestures/primitives/CalculatedElementPosition.h:7,
                 from src/main/cc/com/mycompany/api/gestures/primitives/PointerInteraction.h:7,
                 from src/main/cc/com/mycompany/api/gestures/native/NativeUserInteractionHandler.h:10,
                 from src/main/cc/com/mycompany/linux/api/gestures/UserInteractionHandler.h:4,
                 from src/main/cc/com/mycompany/linux/api/opengl/OpenGlHandler.h:13,
                 from src/main/cc/com/mycompany/linux/api/opengl/OpenGlHandler.cc:1:
external/rapidjson_artifact/include/rapidjson/document.h: At global scope:
external/rapidjson_artifact/include/rapidjson/document.h:2028:15: error: expected unqualified-id before 'bool'
     bool Bool(bool b) { new (stack_.template Push<ValueType>()) ValueType(b); return true; }
               ^~~~
external/rapidjson_artifact/include/rapidjson/document.h:2028:15: error: expected ')' before 'bool'
In file included from src/main/cc/com/mycompany/serialization/JsonSerializer.h:6:0,
                 from bazel-out/k8-dbg/genfiles/src/main/java/com/mycompany/model/common/cc/com/mycompany/model/common/Vector2d.h:13,
                 from bazel-out/k8-dbg/genfiles/src/main/java/com/mycompany/model/common/cc/com/mycompany/model/common/FastVector2d.h:10,
                 from src/main/cc/com/mycompany/api/gestures/primitives/CalculatedElementPosition.h:7,
                 from src/main/cc/com/mycompany/api/gestures/primitives/PointerInteraction.h:7,
                 from src/main/cc/com/mycompany/api/gestures/native/NativeUserInteractionHandler.h:10,
                 from src/main/cc/com/mycompany/linux/api/gestures/UserInteractionHandler.h:4,
                 from src/main/cc/com/mycompany/linux/api/opengl/OpenGlHandler.h:13,
                 from src/main/cc/com/mycompany/linux/api/opengl/OpenGlHandler.cc:1:
external/rapidjson_artifact/include/rapidjson/writer.h:109:15: error: expected unqualified-id before 'bool'
     bool Bool(bool b)           { Prefix(b ? kTrueType : kFalseType); return WriteBool(b); }
               ^~~~
external/rapidjson_artifact/include/rapidjson/writer.h:109:15: error: expected ')' before 'bool'
```

All the errors point to rapidjson but I highly doubt that is the problem. It is probably something I'm doing wrong.

Can someone suggest what I should look for to find the root cause?

Comment: If any of the translation units above happen to include directly or indirectly `<X11/Xlib.h>`, the following gets pulled in "`/usr/include/X11/Xlib.h:#define Bool int`", according to my `grep`. And once the above rapidjson code gets pulled in, hillarity ensues.

Comment: So how do I work with this? Is it a question of ensuring that things are included in a different order?

Comment: Well, ***have*** you determined this to be the actual reason for the compilation errors? It's utterly pointless to make random changes until you've confirmed the reason for the compilation failures. Very rarely do C++ compilation errors get fixed by making random chagnes to the code. And once you do confirm what is the actual reason for the compilation failure, then, by definition, you will know what needs to be done to fix it.